# 'TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL is set to SNAPSHOT' error when using TransactionScope on Memory Optimised Table

Tags: c#, transactionscope, isolation-level, memory-optimized-tables

In Memory disk setup on SQL Server with below up

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csr2P.png)]]

| snapshot_isolation_state | snapshot_isolation_state_desc | is_read_committed_snapshot_on | is_memory_optimized_elevate_to_snapshot_on | is_memory_optimized_enabled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ON | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Code to setup and complete transaction below

```
var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();
                    transactionOptions.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Snapshot;

using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, transactionOptions))
    {
        this.Service.Set(object);
        transaction.Complete();
    }
```

But on transaction.Complete() this error is thrown:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Memory optimized tables and natively compiled modules cannot be accessed or created when the session TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL is set to SNAPSHOT.

To my understanding if `is_memory_optimized_enabled` and `is_memory_optimized_elevate_to_snapshot_on` are set to true I should be able to use `IsolationLevel.Snapshot`?

I set up the in memory Db, created the memory optimized table, then using **TransactionScope** in code to attempt to write to the Db.

I would preferably use **SNAPSHOT** as READCOMMITTED is having intermittent issues with the locking.

READCOMMITTED works with retry logic but would rather use SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Just a word that "in memory" features of SQL Server are really only utilised when you have a couple of tables set to in memory, and they are operated on by a stored procedure. Whether or not you use the in memory feature, tables will be cached in memory anyway

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it right, the problem is that you cannot specify both:

- **MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_ELEVATE_TO_SNAPSHOT**: `1`
- **IsolationLevel**: `Snapshot`

and the same time.

When you use `MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_ELEVATE_TO_SNAPSHOT`, you continue to use **ReadCommitted** as normal.

This is admittedly a little confusing, but makes a bit more sense when you have transactions with both disk-based and in-memory objects.

### Locking issue

For your locking issue:

> I would preferably use `SNAPSHOT` - as `READ COMMITTED` is having intermittent issues with the locking.

The preferred solution there is to turn on:

```
READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT = 1
```

This functions somewhat like "memory optimized elevate to snapshot":

- `memory-optimized` <kbd>elevate to</kbd> snapshot
- `read-committed` <kbd>elevate to</kbd> snapshot

It means that if you are running in `READ_COMMITTED` mode, you will get `SNAPSHOT` isolation enabled for free.

So now you have:

- memory optimized tables elevating to snapshot
- and readcommited transactions elevating to snapshot

Comment: Thanks but I have 'is_read_committed_snapshot_on' set to on and when I set the transactionscope to IsolationLevel.Snapshot I get the error stated in description. When I remove the Transaction IsolationLevel it defaults to Serializable even though the settings from the description are on the sys.databases table

Comment: *" When I remove the Transaction IsolationLevel it defaults to Serializable"* That is ***very*** strange. Unless otherwise specified when you're not using  **System.Transactions**, the `transactionOptions.IsolationLevel` is supposed to default to **ReadCommitted**. What happens if you force it using `transactionOptions.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;`?